# How to get last value that equals the current value in TradingView Pine Script?

Tags: pine-script

I am using Pine Script which is used in tradingview.com.

My question is: how I can get the last value that equals the current value? I thought about using a `for` loop or something else.

I tried this code but it returns an error:

```
getval(x,y) =>
    for i = 1 to 100
        val = valuewhen(i, y, 1)
        val2 = valuewhen(x=i, val, 1)
    val2
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the last value that equals the current value (using pine script version 3), you should write something like this :

```
getval(x,y) =>
    val = 0.0
    val2 = 0.0
    for i = 1 to 100 //has to be indented as well
        val := valuewhen(i,y, 1)
        val2 := valuewhen(x == i, val, 1) //== for a condition, = is to assign a value to a variable
    val2 ? val2 : val //if val2 exists, return val2, else return val)
```

It works, I tried it, when you will be calling your function, don't forget to give it the parameters, for example :

```
getval(1, 3)
```

Comment: Cool, I am glad I was able to help :)